# How do I add two materials to a mesh that is already rendered on the canvas

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to add a colour and an image to a threejs Mesh after its already on the canvas. As far as i am aware if I add a colour and a map using the same material they will blend and theres no way of stopping it. So if I have a white image and a yellow colour the colour will tint the image yellow:

```
let material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
               map: canvasTexture,
               color: 0xCECECE
               });
```

To get around this i am trying to add two materials to the mesh. One with the colour and one with the image

```
let material0 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                color: 0xCECECE
                });

let material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
                map: canvasTexture
              });

var materials = [material0, material1];

mesh.material = materials;
```

At the minute when i try to set the mesh material to be the materials array it goes blank as if it doesn't accept the array as a parameter. Even though threejs documentation says it accepts an array of materials
https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh.material

Another problem I see that might happen, if I get this to work the material with just an image will default to have a white colour therefore not showing the colour of the material below.

So how do I set the image and colour of a mesh material without them blending. Adding two materials seems overcomplicated to me and in the long run might be harder to manage?

**UPDATE**
So my problem ended up being the texture i was using which was a [canvas texture](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/CanvasTexture). I needed to set the fill style of the canvas used in the canvas texture to be opaque. Something like:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)";
```

Then I could go ahead and add multiple materials in an array to the mesh. The material that uses the canvas texture as the map also has to be set to transparent. I also had to set the map.minfilter to be THREE.LinearFilter. Not sure why but at least it now works :)

```
let material0 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    color: 0xf2f2f2
});

let material1 = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    map: canvasTexture,
    transparent: true
});
material1.map.minFilter = THREE.LinearFilter;

var materials = [material1, material0];
mesh.geometry.clearGroups();
mesh.geometry.addGroup( 0, 48, 0 ); 
mesh.geometry.addGroup( 0, 48, 1 ); 
mesh.material = materials;
```

Hope this can help someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> At the minute when i try to set the mesh material to be the materials array it goes blank as if it doesn't accept the array as a parameter.

That probably happens since your geometry does not define any [groups data](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry.groups). This is a requirement for using multiple materials.

> So if I have a white image and a yellow colour the colour will tint the image yellow

This is the expected behavior. The color of the material is multiplied with the sampled color value from the diffuse texture. TBH, a different default behavior would not make sense.

> So how do I set the image and colour of a mesh material without them blending.

If you want to render different parts of the mesh with different materials, then define group data for the respective geometry and use multiple materials. Otherwise consider to duplicate the mesh and assign one material to the original one and the second material to the copy. By adding the copy to the original (`mesh.add( copy )`), you keep both at the same place.

Comment: I don’t understand why there isnt a simple attribute to define how colour and texture blend. Surely theres many use cases where this would be applicable. Your two options seem like they might do the trick for me. Group data might just be what I'm looking for. I also didnt know that i could add a mesh to a mesh? So on a button click i get the mesh, duplicate it, change the material of the original to be a colour and the duplicate to be a texture, then add the duplicate to the original? I will upvote ur answer once i get a chance to try it out and if either option works for me. Thank you